# Preserve mtime with svn checkout, or update svn export

Tags: svn, export, svn-checkout, filemtime

I want to publish a copy of an `svn checkout` on a web-server, which has to be `svn up`'ed daily.

I'd like to preserve the mtime of files (and directories, if possible) of such a checked out copy of an svn repository.

I found that `svn export` would potentially do the job, but then it turns out that you cannot run `svn export` multiple times (i.e. to pick up the recent changes), unless you use `--force`, which seems to cause the whole old copy to be destroyed, and a brand new copy to be checked out — not what I'm looking for.

**What's the best way to keep proper mtime on a read-only svn checkout that has to be updated daily?**

Comment: What is the reason for the requirement of not modifying the mtime in the working copy? Subversion uses that to monitor for changes in its default WC behavior.

Comment: The "working copy" is static, and has to be presentable / reproducible.  I don't want Googlebot to start requesting every single document on my web-site if I simply re-checkout the repo, when not that many files in the repo have changed.  Or to have an inconsistency in a mirror site.